# SSL issues when doing Lynda Course "Learning Python with PyCharm"

Tags: python, pycharm

When finishing off Section 2 I get the following error.

"urllib.error.URLError: "

Answer (score 0):

Change add the context= switch to the response = line.
I don't claim this to be secure, just lets you get on with the course.

```
def load_page(url: str):
    response = urlopen(url, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
    html = response.read().decode('utf8')
    return html
```